# getting double tab strips in fragment

Tags: java, android, tabs, fragment, strip

I Want a tabbed activity for that I have used sliding tabbed layout and tab strip. But don't know why I am getting two strips like below: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG0gm.png)

**SlidingTabLayout**

```
    public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public interface TabColorizer {

        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {

                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }

            tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector));
            tabTitleView.setTextSize(16);
        }


    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SlidingTabStrip**

```
class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
    private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
    private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
    private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

    private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
    private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

    private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
    private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

    private final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;

    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private float mSelectionOffset;

    private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
    private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
        final int themeForegroundColor =  outValue.data;

        mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
                DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

        mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

        mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

        mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
    }

    void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
        mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
        invalidate();
    }

    void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
        mCustomTabColorizer = null;
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
        invalidate();
    }

    void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        final int height = getHeight();
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
                ? mCustomTabColorizer
                : mDefaultTabColorizer;

        // Thick colored underline below the current selection
        if (childCount > 0) {
            View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
            int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
            int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
            int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

            if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
                int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                if (color != nextColor) {
                    color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
                }

                // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
                View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
                right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
            }

            mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

            canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                    height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
        }

        // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
        canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);
    }

    /**
     * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha} value.
     */
    private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
        return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
    }

    /**
     * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
     *
     * @param ratio of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
     *              0.0 will return {@code color2}.
     */
    private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
        final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
        float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
        float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
        float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
        return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
    }

    private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
        private int[] mIndicatorColors;

        @Override
        public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
        }

        void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
            mIndicatorColors = colors;
        }
    }
}

GoFoodCategoryFragment

    public class GoFoodCategoryFragment extends Fragment{


    private ViewPager pager;
    private HomeViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    private CharSequence Titles[]={"CATEGORY","NEAR ME"};
    private int Numboftabs =2;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_go_food, container, false);

        setupUI(view);
        return view;
    }
    void setupUI(View view)
    {

        adapter =  new HomeViewPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_scroll_color);
            }
        });

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }
}

GoFoodCategoryLayout

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.adgatemedia.offerwallsdk.fragments.MainFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.example.siddhi.go_jek.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

HomeViewPagerAdapter

    public class HomeViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[];
    int NumbOfTabs;


    public HomeViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0)
        {
           GoFoodCategoryFragment tab1 = new GoFoodCategoryFragment();
            return tab1;
        }
        else
        {
            GoFoodNearMeFragment tab2 = new GoFoodNearMeFragment();
            return tab2;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this please..

Comment: This is too much of code. Please remove the code that is not relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using a `ViewPager` and `SlidingTabLayout`. You are basically implementing two different tab methods. You only need the `ViewPager` with an `Adapter` like so:

```
private class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> fragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragmentList.add(fragment);
            fragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Code for setting up the `ViewPager` with said adapter:

```
    MainPagerAdapter mainPagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Resources resources = this.getResources();
    mainPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentOne, "fragmentOneTitle");
    mainPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentTwo, "fragmentTwoTitle");

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mainPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply..But the same code I have applied in another application it works fine.. What changes to be made in my code?? @vguzzi

Comment: The changes that you need to make in your code is remove your `SlidingTabLayout` and everything related to it.

Comment: But I want customized tab strip..@vguzzi

Comment: Remove either the `ViewPager` or `SlidingTabStrip` the reason you have two appearing when you run your application is because you have both of them.

Comment: I tried removing view pager i dint get any of the tab..@ vguzzi